# Browser unable to open php page?

Tags: php, linux, shell, networking

First of all I am showing the PHP code ....

```
<?php 

 echo ("hello");

 echo exec("sendip -v -p ipv6 -6s 2001::100 -p tcp -ts 21 -td 21 2001::200 2> 
 &1");

 echo ("hi");

 ?>
```

When I entered the command through linux command line it is working fine.The command is sending a tcp ipv6 packet on 2001::200 machine from 2001::100.

```
[root@udit-pc]# sendip -v  -p ipv6 -6s 2001::100 -p tcp -ts 21 
-td 21 2001::200 > /dev/null &

/* (-v for verbose) */
```

Output of above command ...

```
 Added 34 options
 Initializing module ipv6
 Initializing module tcp
 Finalizing module tcp
 Finalizing module ipv6
 Final packet data:
 60 00 00 00   `...
 /*

  here other packet 
  contents gets printed

  */

 7D 62 00 00   }b..
 61 62 63 64   abcd
 Sent 64 bytes to 2001::200
 Freeing module ipv6
 Freeing module tcp
```

When I execute the php script through command line...

```
[root@udit-pc]# php test.php
Freeing module tcp
```

hellohi gets printed and packet arrived at 2001::200.

But problem arise when I try to run php script through browser...

```
 http:://localhost/test.php
```

hellohi gets printed but packet does not arrive at other machine.

```
 sh: sendip: command not found
```

Also in both case packet contents are not printed at terminal although using verbose option but when directly using command verbose option works fine.

I tried with many things although I do not think they would help like......

1. I added /usr/local/lib and usr/local/bin to PATH variable but no benefit.
2. chmod +s /usr/local/bin/sendip .Sticky bit set but again no benefit.
3. paste the /usr/local/bin/sendip itself in /var/www/html folder although I have changed the PATH variable but as i said i m just using hit n trial getting no clue.....

There are some output snapshots which may further help ....

```
[root@cc html]# echo $PATH
/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin: 
/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/lib

[root@cc html]# locate sendip
.....
/usr/local/bin/sendip
/usr/local/lib/sendip
.....

 [root@cc bin]# chmod +s sendip
 [root@cc bin]# ls -l sendip
 -rwsrwsrwx 1 apache apache 41071 Sep 26 19:41 sendip

 [root@cc bin]# cd /usr/local/lib/
 [root@cc lib]# ls -ld sendip
 drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Sep 28 22:48 sendip
 [root@cc lib]# chmod +s sendip
 [root@cc lib]# ls -ld sendip
 drwsrwsrwx 2 root root 4096 Sep 28 22:48 sendip
```

When file contents are changed .......

```
 <?php
 echo exec("/usr/bin/sendip ........  2 > &1");
 ?>
```

Then oputput is :

```
 [root@cc html]# php test.php
 Freeing module tcp[root@cc html]#
```

On browser....
     No error gets printed but packet still not arrived.

I am stuck in between.Please suggest me what else should I rather try ??????/

Comment: What does exec(...) return?  You could try system() to get further output.

Comment: Most likely a permissions issue, as you have suspected.

Comment: @Brad I also tried this command....   `chown apache:apache test.php` but no benefit again.If perm issue then please suggest me what should i do ??

Comment: @JohnKurlak may be i will try that but it was working fn9 prevoiusly  but nw i reinstalled the sendip and did respective changes as i did earlier......so i think it should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is `sendip()` in the path of the shell being invoked by PHP? You're not checking for error conditions, so possibly you're not actually executing sendip, and just getting a "no such program or file" type errors.

Instead of redirecting the exec()'d command's output to null, redirect it all to the browser so you can see what happens:

```
echo exec("sendiip yada yada yada 2>&1");
```

Comment: output of sendip should appear on other machine not on browser...and if i will not redirect the command output even it would work.`php test.php` is able to send packet on other m/c when i do not use any redirection operator

Comment: Yes, but if sendip is never getting invoked (eg: it's not in the PHP shell's path), then the exec command will output the usual "no such file" error, which is NOT captured into PHP. This is just for debugging purposes. Remember, you running the command dirctly at the command line is a completely DIFFERENT environment than what the same script will see when running under a webserver.

Comment: Is setting PHP PATH is different from setting shell PATH. i used `PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib`. Do i need to do anything else for PHP PATH. sendip is located in `/usr/lib/sendip`. and this one you told me i will try definitely ...thanx for the advice.

Comment: Depends on where you set it. Just try the full path to sendip: `exec("/usr/bin/sendip ....")` and see what happens. If you do get a response on the other end, then it's a pathing issue. If you don't, then it's something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path:

```
exec("/usr/lib/sendip -v -p ipv6 -6s 2001::100 -p tcp -ts 21 -td 21 2001::200 > /dev/null &");
```

Answer (score 0):

The server is most likely not running with the same permissions as the user, you are testing with.

The server is most likely discarding any PATH variable. Make sure that you specify the complete path to `sendip` in the `exec` call.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is solved although I can not say its fully solved but as per my need its working.

What i did is I re-installed the sendip ,then I set its sticky bit and then after that I set the Path variable to as above mentioned in question.

Actually the tool is by default installing the libraries in `/usr/local/lib/sendip` folder and sendip in `/usr/local/bin` folder.

Although after setting PATH variable still I need to use full path in the PHP Script

`/usr/local/bin/sendip -v .....`

(one of my friend suggested me this..)

What I think is PHP Path is something different from Shell PATH.I need to paste sendip to `/usr/bin` and then I need to run `updatedb` before setting its sticky bit if I don't want to mention full path in PHP Script .Now this command will work fine in PHP Script.
 `sendip -v .........`

Although May be I am wrong but this all works fine for me.